# Typescript string.split with regex with char followed by space and space only

Tags: regex, string, typescript, split

I have a string of this type:

```
string = "test1; test2, test3 test4;test5"
```

I need to split it and get an array with the 5 words. I do this:

```
let arrayTo:string[] = string.split(/;|,|, |; | /);
```

but what I get is an array of 7 elements, two of them are empty strings:

```
["test1","","test2","","test3","test4","test5"]
```

I would like to consider , and ; followed by whitespace as one entity and split on them, but with this regex it splits also on the whitespace that follows these characters. But I need also to split by whitespace alone (in this case, it correctly splits `test3` and `test4` in two entities).
What is the correct way to do this?

Comment: You split by `;` (semi-column) first, instead of `; ` (semi-column space).

Comment: Try `split(/[;,]\s*|\s+/)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
string.split(/[;,]\s*|\s+/)
```

The regex matches

- `[;,]\s*` - a `;` or `,` and then 0+ whitespaces
- `|`  - or
- `\s+` - 1+ whitespaces.

JS demo:

```js
string = "test1; test2, test3 test4;test5";
console.log(string.split(/[;,]\s*|\s+/));
```